# Adding filter in syslog-ng.conf

Tags: syslog-ng

How to add filter for tag in syslog ng? As per RFC3164 the payload to syslog ng will be in the format HEADER [tag]:Message.
As per my requirement the [tag] will be containing [ServiceName-Group] where service name will the application name and Group will be "SECURITY" or "INFO". 
So the filter is required for the following case:
Any message with local0.info and group name "SECURITY" should go to /var/log/Security.log
Any message with local0.info and group name "INFO" should go to /var/log/info.log.

Please help me to find the filter for the above two cases.

Answer (score 0):

check the [syslog-ng documentation](http://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/administration-guide/log-filter-and-route-log-messages-using-log-paths-flags-and-filters/filters) for details about how to use filters. 
For your usecase, you'll probably want to use the facility(local0) and the level(info) filters, plus a filter to match the service group, something like match("[groupname]" value("MESSAGE")). Put together it will be something like:

```
filter demo_filter { facility(local0) and level(info) and match("[groupname]" value("MESSAGE")); };
```